# Unity2D: How to make my player invulnerable for X amount of time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my player invulnerable from objects hitting him for a few seconds after he resets back to the center of the game, meaning I don't want anything to hurt him and I don't want the player to move for 5 seconds, but i'm not sure of how to do that! I searched it up but results that I found doesn't match up with my code. Anyway this is my playermovement script:

```
private Animator anim;
public float speed = 15f;
public static Vector3 target;
private bool touched;
private bool canmove;
Vector3 startPosition;


void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    var movementDirection = (target - transform.position).normalized;

    if (movementDirection.x != 0 || movementDirection.y != 0) {
        anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
        anim.SetFloat("SpeedX", movementDirection.x);
        anim.SetFloat("SpeedY", movementDirection.y);
        anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float LastInputX = transform.position.x - target.x;
    float LastInputY = transform.position.y - target.y;

    if (touched) {
        if (LastInputX != 0 || LastInputY != 0) {
            anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
            if (LastInputX < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 1f);
            } else if (LastInputX > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", -1f);
            } else {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 0f);
            }
            if (LastInputY > 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 1f);
            } else if (LastInputY < 0) {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", -1f);
            } else {
                anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 0f);
            }
        }
    }else{
        touched = false;
        anim.SetBool ("walking", false);            
    }
}
```

}

And this is my player health script:

```
public int curHealth;
public int maxHealth = 3;
Vector3 startPosition;
bool  invincible = false;

void Start ()
{
    curHealth = maxHealth;
    startPosition = transform.position;
}


void Update ()
{

    if (curHealth > maxHealth) {
        curHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    if (curHealth <= 0) {

        Die ();
    }
}

void Die ()
{
    //Restart
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
}


public void Damage(int dmg)
{
    curHealth -= dmg;
    Reset();
}

void Reset ()
{
    transform.position = startPosition;
    PlayerMovement.target = startPosition;

}
```

}

So to be more simple, I want to make my player invulnerable (once he reset back in the center of the screen) from getting hit from enemies for 5 seconds and people who are playing my player can not move for 5 seconds. Thank you! (My game is a topdown 2d click to move game)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick. At least point you in the right direction.

Simple explanation, i changed invincible to be a time, a time in the future.
Then we simply add a time in the future to it at some event, and from that event onward to the point in the future we want him invincible.

So at every event where he would take damage we check, is now in the future of invincible or is invincible in the future of now. that is your bool.

```
DateTime invincible = DateTime.Now;

public void Damage(int dmg)
{
    if(invincible <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        curHealth -= dmg;
        Reset();
    }
}

void Reset ()
{
    transform.position = startPosition;
    PlayerMovement.target = startPosition;
    invincible = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
}
```

if you want a helper method like this

```
bool IsInvincible(){
    return invincible <= DateTime.Now;
}
```

Then you can change out the `if(invincible <= DateTime.Now)` with `if(IsInvincible())` in your `public void Damage(int dmg)`

Comment: Thank you for replying back, one question though: is DateTime a bool?

Comment: Nop, DateTime is as it says a Date Time meaning that it is the type we use when picking time. like int is whole numbers, bool is true/false etc. I added a description of what is happening. So DateTime.Now is the time on your computer NOW!!!! hehe

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand, do I replace the "DateTime.Now" with the time on my computer, or am I misunderstanding. Thank you though

Comment: Because I'm getting an error saying that "DateTime" does not exist in the current context

Comment: no not at all the code `DateTime.Now` picks the time of the client. If youre missing Datetime then you might be missing alot of neat stuff as you must not have `import System;` at the very top of your class http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-get-system-time-in-unity.29667/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I fixed my problem by using IEnumerator yield return new WaitForSeconds and enable

Answer (score 0):

In game development, you have to keep in mind that everything happens within a frame update. I like to use coroutines to implement invincibility frames in Unity. A coroutine is simply a method that runs in parallel to the main update loop and resumes where it left off in the next update.

```
float dmg = 100.0f;
bool isHitByEnemy = false
bool isInvulnerable = false

void Demage()
{
    //some dmg logic

    if (isHitByEnemy && isInvulnerable == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine("OnInvulnerable");
    }
}

IEnumerator OnInvulnerable()
{
    isInvulnerable  = true;
    dmg = 0.0f; 

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); //how long player invulnerable

    dmg = 100.0f;
    isInvulnerable  = false;
}
```