# Taking damage in unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a script where the player triggers with the enemy and takes the damage from him.

```
public class PlayersHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth;
    public int maxHealth;
    private bool inCollider = false;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
     if(inCollider == false){
     if(collision.CompareTag("Enemy")){
        inCollider = true;
     }
     }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision){
        if(inCollider == true){
        if(collision.CompareTag("Enemy")){
           currentHealth--;
           inCollider = false;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem is that I am taking to much damage because of this going in/out of the trigger collider.

I have tried to fix that by making bool "inCollider" that should solve the problem.
Unfortunately, problem still remains.

I am a newbie to Unity and C#, so I would be glad to see alternative ways to do a script like this.

Maybe I should do this in enemy attack script?

Comment: It looks like you need to implement iFrames (invincibility frames). Basically a timer will start when your player takes damage, and player can't be damaged until the timer hits 0.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554292/unity2d-how-to-make-my-player-invulnerable-for-x-amount-of-time

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're making some kind of platformer or sidescroller here. Typically, games will give you a set amount of seconds after taking damage where you're invincible. In most Super Mario games, for example, after taking damage Mario flashes and is invincible for 158 frames, or 2.528 seconds.

Other common solutions to this problem include knocking the player away from the enemy on collision, or killing the enemy that caused the player to take damage.